# 2つのCSVファイル内の値の平均値を比較をするには

Tags: macos, sh

- file1とfile2のA列の平均値
- file1とfile2のB列の平均値

をシェルスクリプトで比較するためには、どのような方法がありますでしょうか。
CSVのフォーマットは、下記のようになります。

```
A,B
28960,0.072569
28960,0.072569
31856,0.078464
34752,0.072569
37648,0.072569
43440,0.072569
46336,0.072569
49232,0.072569
55024,0.072569
60816,0.072569
63712,0.072569
66608,0.072569
69504,0.072569
72400,0.072569
75296,0.072569
78192,0.078464
86880,0.072569
89776,0.072569
92672,0.072569
95568,0.078464
110048,0.072569
112944,0.072569
115840,
121632,
124528,0.072569
127424,0.072569
133216,0.072569
139008,0.072569
144800,0.072569
144800,0.072569
153488,
156384,
165072,
188240,
191136,
196928,0.078464
202720,
```

Comment: phpのタグが指定されてますが、平均値の取得と比較のプログラムをphpで実装する、ということでしょうか？それであればどんなphpコードを書いてみたのかを提示してください。shで求めたいのであればphpタグは不要かと思いますので削除お願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。PHPタグを削除いたしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

シェルスクリプトであればやはり古典的にawkだろう、ということで。フィールドが増えても対応出来ます。

```
#! /bin/sh

FILES="nanoha.csv fate.csv"
for f in $FILES; do
  tmpfile=`mktemp -t csv`
  tmpfiles=($tmpfiles $tmpfile)
  trap "rm -f $tmpfile" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTERM

  awk -F, '
    NR == 1 {
      ncols = NF;
      for(i = 0; i < NF; i++) {
        cols[i] = $(i + 1)
      }
    }

    1 < NR {
      nrows++;
      for(i = 0; i < ncols; i++) {
        sum[i] += $(i + 1)
      }
    }

    END {
      for(i = 0; i < ncols; i++) {
        print cols[i] " " sum[i]/nrows;
      }
    }
  ' < $f | sort > $tmpfile
done

echo FILE $FILES
join -a 1 -a 2 ${tmpfiles[@]}
```

出力 (データは適当な物を使っています):

```
FILE nanoha.csv fate.csv
A 4.75 1.75
B 5 8
```

Answer (score 2):

これってtshark云々関係なくて、単純にcsv fileに書いてある値の平均値をsh scriptで求めたいだけですよね？
そしたら、出力したcsvのformatが分かればなんとでもなると思います。
まずは、実際に出力したcsvを抜粋して載せたら良いんじゃないでしょうか？

---

コメントして放置するのもなんなんで、bashで作ってみました。

とりあえず、以下のsh scriptを作って、実行権与えてあげる。ファイル名を『csvAve.sh』とかにしたとして`./csvAve.sh file1.csv file2.csv`ってやるとそれぞれの平均出します。

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$','
BC=/usr/bin/bc

function getAve(){
  sum0=0
  sum1=0
  cnt0=0
  cnt1=0

  while read line; do
    col=(`echo "${line}"`)

    if [ -n "${col[0]}" ]
    then
      sum0=`echo "${col[0]} + ${sum0}" | ${BC}`
      cnt0=`echo "${cnt0} + 1" | ${BC}`
    fi

    if [ -n "${col[1]}" ]
    then
      sum1=`echo "${col[1]} + ${sum1}" | ${BC}`
      cnt1=`echo "${cnt1} + 1" | ${BC}`
    fi
  done < $1

  ave0=`echo "${sum0} / ${cnt0}" | ${BC}`
  ave1=`echo "scale=8; ${sum1} / ${cnt1}" | ${BC}`
  echo ${ave0}, ${ave1}
}

sum=0
for path in "$@"; do
  ave=(`getAve ${path}`)
  sum=`echo "${ave[1]} + ${sum}" | ${BC} `
  echo "${path}: ${ave[0]} ${ave[1]}"
done

echo "ave: `echo "scale=8; ${sum} / $#" | ${BC}`"
```

1行目のheader行無視する処理無いのは相変わらずですが...少し直してみました。
A,Bそれぞれの平均を出して、全ファイルのBの平均を出します。
B列が欠測しててもA列有効にしちゃってますけど、良いのかな？

> data1.csv: 102585  .07345325
>   data2.csv: 100968  .07338210
>   ave: .07341767

Comment: はい、その通りです。ありがとうございます。
出力したcsvのフォーマットをのせます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
はい、”,”の前の列、","の後の列の値をそれぞれ計算したいです。
わかりにくかったので、A列B列に修正します。

Answer (score 2):

半分ネタです。

sh スクリプトでということですが、素の sh や bash では実数が扱えないので、ksh あるいは zsh が必要です。スクリプトは次のような実装になります:

```
#!/bin/ksh

set -u

calc() {
  typeset -lE ws ws_sum irtt irtt_sum
  typeset ws_n=0
  typeset irtt_n=0

  read
  while IFS=, read ws irtt; do
    if  [[ -n $ws ]]; then
      let ws_sum+=ws
      let ws_n++
    fi
    if [[ -n $irtt ]];then
      let irtt_sum+=irtt
      let irtt_n++
    fi
  done

  printf '%.4f,%.4f\n' "$((ws_sum / ws_n))" "$((irtt_sum / irtt_n))"
}

for csv_name in "$@"; do
  echo "$csv_name,$(calc <"$csv_name")"
done
```

これを `calc.ksh` として、入力が `a.csv`、`b.csv`、`c.csv` というファイルにあるなら、次のように実行します。

```
$ ./calc.ksh a.csv b.csv c.csv
a.csv,94305.6410,0.0508
b.csv,92672.0000,0.0514
c.csv,91118.0488,0.0519
```

ピュアシェルで書きましたが、awk などを利用したほうが速いでしょうね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
kshのインストールおよびawkのインストールをしました。

awkを使う場合もご教示いただければたすかります。

Answer (score 2):

zsh/ksh や bc, awk で処理する方法が回答で出されていますので、[jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)(v1.4) を使ってみました。

```
$ cat input.dat | jq -s -r -R '
    def average(v): map(.[v] | select(.!=null) | tonumber) | add / length;
    split("\n") |
    [(.[0] | split(",") | map("Average of "+.+" = ")),
     (.[1:] | map(split(",")) |
       [(average(0)|tostring), (average(1)|tostring)])] |
    (map(.[0]) | join("")), (map(.[1]) | join(""))'
=>
Average of A = 100968.64864864865
Average of B = 0.07338210344827589
```

こんな方法もあるという事で、ご参考までにどうぞ。